# How do i open a new command prompt from a batch file in a different color

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I can't seem to open a new [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) in a different color. The batch file opens a total of seven command windows and i would like for them to be in different colors.

I have tried adding in the `color` command in different positions but it never opens the **new** command prompt in the color specified, it always defaults to the black background.

This is what I thought would work:

```
cd "C:\jboss_cache\bin\"
start "1 - JBoss-CACHE" cmd /k color 18 standalone-application.bat
```

but this runs the batch file in standard output.

If I simply run:

```
start "1 - JBoss-CACHE" color 18
```

the new Command Prompt opens in the desired color but this obviously doesn't run the commands I need.

Comment: Try editing your question, deleting what you thought would work, copying and pasting the actual code from your batch file, then selecting the pasted code, and pressing the **`{}`** button to format it properly. If we cannot see exactly what you're using, we cannot know if it is correct, and what you've posted as text with all of those doublequotes is not valid batch file syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Compo for the advice. I have edited the question so hopefully it reads a little better.

Comment: You can join/concatenate multiple instructions/commands on one line using an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Create a little "wrapper" batch file like this one, called "dojob.cmd":

```
@echo off
color %1
%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

You then call it in the following way

```
start "windows name" dojob <color> <your_application_name> [optional parameters]
```

i. e. the command

```
start "All doc files" dojob 70 dir *.doc
```

will open a new window with grey background and black writing where `dir *doc` will have been executed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however i don't think my question was very clear!. The original batch file opens a number of other commands prompts. These other command prompts run various applications and i would like for these to open in different color so that i can easily tell what is what. I actually don't care what the original batch file color is.

Comment: I should have called my script "wrapper function" and I should have made it a bit more "variable". Please look again at my edited solution ...

Comment: This worked a treat for me. Unfortunately i don't have enough rep to upvote the answer but thanks for the feedback. Just wondering if there is anyway to do this all in one batch file instead of using the wrapper??

Comment: I tried but I haven't found a way either. You can define a procedure `:procname` within a batch file and call it via `call :procname <arguments ...>` but unfortunately you cannot use that procedure within a `start` command. So, the (universal) wrapper function cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the very start of your standalone-application.bat file this code:

```
color <desired color>
cls
```

name it cw.bat (short for colored window)

Then in your main.bat just write

```
start standalone-application.bat
```